# Visual Studio Find & Replace characters at both ends of a string

Tags: regex, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, replace

Can anyone tell me how I can use Visual Studio Find and Replace in Files (Ctrl+Shift+H) to find all occurrences of:

```
<TextBox*IDTextBox"
```

and change it to:

```
<Button*IDButton"
```

where the * wildcard represents an arbitrary string.

I have many Textboxes defined and I want to redefine them as Buttons.  For example ….

```
<TextBox x:Name="Name1IDTextBox" Grid.Column="1"
<TextBox x:Name="Name2IDTextBox" Grid.Column="1"
<TextBox x:Name="Name3IDTextBox" Grid.Column="1"
```

Becomes ...

```
<Button x:Name="Name1IDButton" Grid.Column="1"
<Button x:Name="Name2IDButton" Grid.Column="1"
<Button x:Name="Name3IDButton" Grid.Column="1"
```

The wildcard * represents  x:Name="Name1

I know there are plenty of examples but they're all in C# and I can't translate them to retain the contents of the wildcard using the Find and Replace Window.

I've tried

[image]

but all that gave me was `<Button.*IdentityIDButton"` when what I want are the characters represented by *.

Comment: I'll update my question with an example.

Comment: In the code you have posted you have `Name1IDTextBox` so just replace `IDTextBox` with `IDButton`. I am not sure how you will change the type though because you may want a textbox in some cases.

Comment: mjwills and CodingYoshi you did not read my question fully. 
I stated that the * wildcard represents an arbitrary string.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  I've been wading through the Grouping Constructs doco for a couple of hours without success.  Your answer helped me get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example you posted it is sufficient to replace `TextBox` with `Button`. If your actual problem is more difficult than that, you can use backreferences.

Enable regular expressions in the replace dialog and then:

In the *Find what* part of the dialog type `<TextBox(.*)IDTextBox"`

In the *Replace with* part type `<Button$1IDButton"`

The parentheses around `.*` capture whatever is matched by `.*`. `$1` refers back to that capture and can be used in the replacement.

[image: Find and replace dialog]

Answer (score 0):

First, enable **Regular Expressions** in the search and replace form.  In the full dialog, there is a checkbox for this.  In the "quick find" popup, toggle the third icon under the search terms:

[image: Screenshot]

If you want to match *exactly* the element structure you specified, fill in the following terms:

**Search**: `<(TextBox) x:Name="([^"]*)\1"`
**Replace**: `<Button x:Name="$2Button"`

You could, however, make some minor tweaks to handle cases where `x:Name` isn't the first attribute, or where `x:Name` appears on a separate line.  This could be very handy if there are inconsistencies in your declarations.

**Search**: `<(TextBox)(\s+[^>]*)x:Name="([^"]*)\1"`
**Replace**: `<Button$2x:Name="$3Button"`

The latter would successfully transform the following:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Name1IDTextBox" />
<TextBox
  x:Name="Name2IDTextBox" Grid.Column="1" />
<TextBox x:Name="Name3IDTextBox" Grid.Column="1" />
```

...into:

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Name1IDButton" />
<Button
  x:Name="Name2IDButton" Grid.Column="1" />
<Button x:Name="Name3IDButton" Grid.Column="1" />
```

---

**Character Classes**

You asked about the presence of `[^"]` and `[^>]` in my search patterns.  These are *character classes*.  `[abc]` says *"match the character `a`, `b`, or `c`"*.  `[a-z]` means *"match any character between `a` and `z`"*.  If the first character inside the brackets is `^`, then the character class is negated, e.g., `[^abc]` means *"match any character **except** `a`, `b`, or `c`"*.

In my case, I used `[^>]*` to gobble up any characters *except* `>`, because I only wanted to capture any attributes between `<TextBox` and `x:Name`.  I don't ever want to capture *beyond* the end of an element.  If, for example, there *isn't* an `x:Name` attribute, I wouldn't want to match `Grid.Column="1" OtherProperty="X" /> ... more elements ... <Label x:Name`.

Similarly, I use `[^"]` to make sure I don't consume any characters beyond the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  I can't find an explanation of the " and > in [^"] and [^"].  Would you mind elaborating what they do?

Comment: Added an explanation in my answer.